# Retrieve and unjumble cookie data from superagent response header

Tags: node.js, cookies, superagent

I'm using supertest and trying to get the cookie data cleanly

```
agent.post('/login').send('username:u','password:p').end(function(err, res) {
    agent.cookie = res.req._headers.cookie;
});
```

But to cookie data I get is jumbled up

> `connect.sid=s%3Afc20GaiFXGNju1rxqDSOEiA4.W3XfTacI0xhk4gQ9Bdh1LLC%2FlhjnAwVmQkUX%2F7%2FJEAo`

instead of cleanly like this (and the above is even longer for some reason)

> `{ 'connect.sid': 'T0jrnU09DzCYN68FsgspuY5g' }`

How do I get the latter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
require('cookie').parse(decodeURIComponent(cookie))
```